# How to use the setActiveItem in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to have -when the page loads- the middle tab be the active tab ive been all over the internet looking into setactiveitem but have gotten no where

how do i use the setActiveItem?

here is the code of my main.js with the tabpanel and function.

```
var MainTabPanel = Ext.define('Crystal.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
fullscreen: true,
xtype:'Maintab',


 launch: function(){ console.log('launch'); 

   MainTabPanel.setActiveItem(2);
 },

requires: [


    'Crystal.view.docCarousel',
    'Crystal.view.Contact',
    'Crystal.view.Calculator',
],


config: {

layout: {
    type: 'card',
    animation: {
        type: 'slide',
        direction: 'left'}
},
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    items: [


           {xtype:'Calculator',
           },



        {
            xtype:'docCarousel',

        },
        {
            xtype:'ContactForm',


        }
    ]
}
 });
```

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the `activeItem` config for your `tabpanel` to `1` since you only have 3 tabs(0 ,1 ,2). So `1` will be the active tab when the app loads.

```
var MainTabPanel = Ext.define('Crystal.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    fullscreen: true,
    xtype:'Maintab',
    ...
    config: {
        ...,
        activeItem: 1,
        ...
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Also i don't think you need the `launch` function.

Comment: A small note: if you're using Sencha Architect 2, the `activeItem` option is erroneously specified on the `TabBar` config instead of the `TabPanel` config.  You'll need to manually enter the option onto `TabPanel`'s config.